# Generating regularly spaced sample points in qgis based on ratio of area

Tags: qgis, sampling

I am generating sample locations in irregular shaped polygons in qgis. In my situation, there are often many polygons in one shapefile all with unique shapes that need a certain number of sample units on regular spacing.

Currently, I am only able to work with one polygon at a time using the following process:

First, I use the qgis generate a regular grid tool. As I have found, this will generate a grid over the extent of the polygon. The points are not constrained to be within the shape. I have to guess a number and hope its the correct amount.

Second, I clip the new sample unit layer and the polygon layer so that only points that fall in the polygon are in the new layer.

Third, I count the number of sample units and see if it is an appropriate number. If it is not, I start over at step one with a different number of points for the regular grid.

My idea is that it would be great to automate this process using Python. I am a novice Python programmer.

The logic that I have developed in my head is as follows: (I am going to use the terms Polygon, Sample, and SampleClipped)

I would like to use some sort of Do Until procedure for each polygon. It would first create a grid starting at 1 sample unit in the grid. On each iteration, the loop would include clipping the Sample and check SampleClipped to see if it meets a specified ratio (say 1 sample unit per 4 acres, assuming that acres is in the Polygon attributes). If 1 sample unit in the grid does not meet this ratio, it would try 2 and so on until it meets the ratio. Since often, there are more than 1 polygons in a shapefile, it would need to loop through all polygons in the shapefile.

Another option would be the same procedure above except there would be a field in the attribute table that is Minimum Number Sample Units. The code would loop until the first instance in which it is at least that number of sample units. It can be over that number but not under.

Comment: Sampling polygons the way you want to is pretty simple in R, and probably as simple in arcpy. Not sure pyqgis has equivalent built-in functions, so it may not be the best choice for a newbie programmer.

Comment: Should be doable. I would get the features in a layer.getfeatures() request then iterate over them. Each feature has a feature.geometry() method and geometry().area() will get you the area.